# ListView row containing another ListView

Tags: android, android-layout

I am using `ListView` inside the row of another `ListView`. In `wishlist.xml`, I have one `ListView`. That items were in wishlist_items.xml, In that wishlist_items also having one more listView. that was designed in `wishlist_items_advisors.xml`. My problem is that send `ListView` is showing only one item. Can any one tell me how to fix this? 
And the adapters also given below.

**wishlist.xml**

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/logo_container"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/logo"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:contentDescription="@string/app_name" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/title_container"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/titleredbg"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/title"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/wishlist_title"
                android:textColor="#fff"
                android:textSize="20sp" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/help"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:contentDescription="@string/app_name" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/add_person"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
            android:padding="5dp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="100" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="57"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="100" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/wishlist_name_text"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight="40"
                android:text="@string/wishlist_name"
                android:textColor="@color/Black" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/wishlist_email_text"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight="60"
                android:text="@string/wishlist_email"
                android:textColor="@color/Black" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/wishlist_relation_text"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="43"
            android:text="@string/wishlist_relation"
            android:textColor="@color/Black" />
    </LinearLayout>



    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/items_footer"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="100" >

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/listView_main"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:divider="@null"
            android:dividerHeight="4dp"
            android:visibility="visible" >
        </ListView>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/empty"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:background="#fff"
            android:gravity="center" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="@string/no_data"
                android:textColor="#000" >
            </TextView>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

**wishlist_items.xml**

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/hr1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:background="#D2D2D2" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#fff"
        android:baselineAligned="false"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:weightSum="100" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="57"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="100" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/wishlist_name"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight="40"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:maxLines="2"
                android:text="John John John John John John"
                android:textColor="@color/Black" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/wishlist_email"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight="60"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:maxLines="2"
                android:text="krishna.mondeddu@gmail.com krishna.mondeddu@gmail.com"
                android:textColor="@color/Black" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="43"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="100" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/wishlist_relation"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="60"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:maxLines="2"
                android:text="Birthday  Birthday  vv Birthday Birthday"
                android:textColor="@color/Black" />

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_weight="40" >

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/editButton"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/deleteButton"
                    android:background="@drawable/wishlistediticon"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/app_name" />

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/deleteButton"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"

                    android:contentDescription="@string/app_name" />
            </RelativeLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/hr4"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="#D2D2D2" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/gift_advisor_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/wishlist_getadvisor"
            android:textColor="@color/Black" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/hr1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="#D2D2D2" />

    <ListView android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
       ></ListView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/hr5"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="#D2D2D2" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:background="#fff"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
         >


        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/invite_advisor"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"

            android:contentDescription="@string/app_name" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

**wishlist_items_advisors.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#fff"
    android:baselineAligned="false"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
    android:paddingTop="5dp"
    android:weightSum="100" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_weight="57"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="100" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/advisor_name_text"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="40"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:maxLines="2"
            android:text="John John"
            android:textColor="@color/Black" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/advisor_email_text"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="60"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:maxLines="2"
            android:text="krishna."
            android:textColor="@color/Black" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_weight="43" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/status_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/deleteButton"
            android:text="Accept" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/deleteButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"

            android:contentDescription="@string/app_name" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

**CustomAdapter**

```
public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

        private String guestIds[]=null;
        private String names[]=null;
        private String emails[] = null;
        private String relationships[] = null;
        private String occasions[] = null;
        DisplayImageOptions doption=null;
        private ImageLoadingListener animateFirstListener =null;
        private Context context=null;

        public CustomAdapter(Activity activity,String[] guestId,String[] name,String[] email,String[] relationship, String[] occasion)
        {   

            this.context=activity;
            this.guestIds = guestId;
            this.names =name;
            this.emails = email;
            this.relationships = relationship;
            this.occasions = occasion;
            doption=new DisplayImageOptions.Builder().showImageForEmptyUri(R.drawable.ic_empty).showImageOnFail(R.drawable.ic_error).showStubImage(R.drawable.ic_stub).cacheInMemory(true).cacheOnDisc(true).displayer(new RoundedBitmapDisplayer(5)).build();
            animateFirstListener = new AnimateFirstDisplayListener();
        }

        @Override   
        public int getViewTypeCount() {
            return 2;
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemViewType(int position) {
            //CustomAdapter item = (CustomAdapter) getItem(position);
            if (isItemAnAd(position)) {
                return 0;
              } else {
                return 1;
              }
        }
        private boolean isItemAnAd(int position) {
              // Place an ad at the first 
              return (position == 0);
            }
        @Override
        public Object getItem(int arg0) {
            return arg0;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int arg0) {
            return arg0;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            View view = convertView;
            final ViewHolder holder;

            if (convertView == null) {
                view = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.wishlist_items, parent, false);
                holder = new ViewHolder();
                holder.wishlistName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.wishlist_name);
                holder.wishlistEmail = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.wishlist_email);
                holder.wishlistRelation = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.wishlist_relation);
                holder.wishGiftAdvisorText = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.gift_advisor_text);
                holder.advisorListview = (ListView)  view.findViewById(R.id.listView);
                holder.inviteAdvisor = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.invite_advisor);

                view.setTag(holder);
            } else {
                holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
            }

            holder.wishlistName.setText(names[position]);
            holder.wishlistEmail.setText(emails[position]);
            holder.wishlistRelation.setText(relationships[position]);
            holder.wishGiftAdvisorText.setText(getResources().getString( R.string.wishlist_getadvisor)+" "+names[position]+"'s "+getResources().getString( R.string.wishlist_title) );
            GuestId = guestIds[position];
            holder.wishlistName.setTypeface(tf);
            holder.wishlistEmail.setTypeface(tf);
            holder.wishlistRelation.setTypeface(tf);
            holder.wishGiftAdvisorText.setTypeface(tf);

            if(occasions[position].contains("[")) {
                try {
                    array = new JSONArray(occasions[position]);
                    System.out.println(array.toString(2));
                    //loadOccasionData(array);


                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    if(array!= null) {

                        advisorIds = new String[array.length()];
                        advisorNames = new String[array.length()];
                        advisorEmails = new String[array.length()];
                        advisorRelationships = new String[array.length()];
                        advisorStatuses = new String[array.length()];

                        for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
                            JSONObject c;
                            try {

                                c = array.getJSONObject(i);

                                // Storing each json item in variable

                                advisorIds[i] = c.getString("advisor_id");
                                advisorNames[i] = c.getString("name");
                                advisorEmails[i] = c.getString("email");
                                advisorRelationships[i] = c.getString("relationship");
                                advisorStatuses[i] = c.getString("status");

                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }

                        }
                        CustomAdvisorAdapter adapter = new CustomAdvisorAdapter(WishList.this,
                                advisorIds, advisorNames, advisorEmails, advisorRelationships , advisorStatuses);
                        holder.advisorListview.setAdapter(adapter);

                    } 


                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } else {

                holder.advisorListview.setAdapter(null);

            }



            return view;
        }

        private  class AnimateFirstDisplayListener extends SimpleImageLoadingListener {

            final List<String> displayedImages = Collections.synchronizedList(new LinkedList<String>());

            @Override
            public void onLoadingComplete(String imageUri, View view, Bitmap loadedImage) {
                if (loadedImage != null) {
                    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) view;
                    boolean firstDisplay = !displayedImages.contains(imageUri);
                    if (firstDisplay) {
                        FadeInBitmapDisplayer.animate(imageView, 500);
                        displayedImages.add(imageUri);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        private class ViewHolder {
            public TextView wishlistName;
            public TextView wishlistEmail;
            public TextView wishlistRelation;
            public TextView wishGiftAdvisorText;
            public ListView advisorListview;
            public ImageButton inviteAdvisor;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return names.length;
        }
    }
```

**CustomAdvisorAdapter**

```
public class CustomAdvisorAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

        private String advisorIds[]=null;
        private String advisorNames[]=null;
        private String advisorEmails[] = null;
        private String advisorRelationships[] = null;
        private String advisorStatuses[] = null;
        DisplayImageOptions doption=null;
        private ImageLoadingListener animateFirstListener =null;
        private Context context=null;

        public CustomAdvisorAdapter(Activity activity,String[] advisorId,String[] advisorName,String[] advisorEmail,String[] advisorRelationship, String[] advisorStatus)
        {   

            this.context=activity;
            this.advisorIds = advisorId;
            this.advisorNames =advisorName;
            this.advisorEmails = advisorEmail;
            this.advisorRelationships = advisorRelationship;
            this.advisorStatuses = advisorStatus;
            doption=new DisplayImageOptions.Builder().showImageForEmptyUri(R.drawable.ic_empty).showImageOnFail(R.drawable.ic_error).showStubImage(R.drawable.ic_stub).cacheInMemory(true).cacheOnDisc(true).displayer(new RoundedBitmapDisplayer(5)).build();
            animateFirstListener = new AnimateFirstDisplayListener();
        }


        @Override
        public Object getItem(int arg0) {
            return arg0;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int arg0) {
            return arg0;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            View viewAdvisor = convertView;
            final ViewHolder advisorHolder;

            if (convertView == null) {
                viewAdvisor = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.wishlist_items_advisor, parent, false);
                advisorHolder = new ViewHolder();
                advisorHolder.advisorNameText = (TextView) viewAdvisor.findViewById(R.id.advisor_name_text);
                advisorHolder.advisorEmailText = (TextView) viewAdvisor.findViewById(R.id.advisor_email_text);
                advisorHolder.statusText = (TextView) viewAdvisor.findViewById(R.id.status_text);


                viewAdvisor.setTag(advisorHolder);
            } else {
                advisorHolder = (ViewHolder) viewAdvisor.getTag();
            }

            advisorHolder.advisorNameText.setText(advisorNames[position]);
            advisorHolder.advisorEmailText.setText(advisorEmails[position]);
            advisorHolder.statusText.setText(advisorStatuses[position]);

            advisorHolder.advisorNameText.setTypeface(tf);
            advisorHolder.advisorEmailText.setTypeface(tf);
            advisorHolder.statusText.setTypeface(tf);


            return viewAdvisor;
        }

        private  class AnimateFirstDisplayListener extends SimpleImageLoadingListener {

            final List<String> displayedImages = Collections.synchronizedList(new LinkedList<String>());

            @Override
            public void onLoadingComplete(String imageUri, View view, Bitmap loadedImage) {
                if (loadedImage != null) {
                    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) view;
                    boolean firstDisplay = !displayedImages.contains(imageUri);
                    if (firstDisplay) {
                        FadeInBitmapDisplayer.animate(imageView, 500);
                        displayedImages.add(imageUri);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        private class ViewHolder {
            public TextView advisorNameText;
            public TextView advisorEmailText;
            public TextView statusText;

        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return names.length;
        }
    }
```

Comment: This question is excessively long. Instead of posting code/layout files here, you should share whole project(sample) so that someone can try and could help you out!

Comment: why you don't use expandable list for your purpose ? i think you need override `onMeasure`

Comment: `Listview row having another listview` tells one thing: Use an [`ExpandableListView`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html)

Comment: @Shayanpourvatan i can go with expandable but here i have to work on this only.. can you explain how to implement onMeasure here. i tried with http://nex-otaku-en.blogspot.in/2010/12/android-put-listview-in-scrollview.html?showComment=1391062922412 but that is working on Scroll view only

Comment: i do this trick for `Expanable list`, for that i create one class that extends `ExpandableListView` and in that i override `onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec)`

Comment: You should NOT put a list inside another list.  (Scrollable inside a scrollable).  Suggest making your bigger list something else (maybe a vertical LinearLaoyout).

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible to make a scrollable view inside a scrollable view. But as a work around this, and only in case that this listviews doesn't take much memory if all views are loaded.
you can use this

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class NonScrollableListView extends ListView {
    public NonScrollableListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        // Do not use the highest two bits of Integer.MAX_VALUE because they are
        // reserved for the MeasureSpec mode
        int heightSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(Integer.MAX_VALUE >> 2, MeasureSpec.AT_MOST);
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightSpec);
        getLayoutParams().height = getMeasuredHeight();
    }

}
```

**Again, it's not good to use this workaround**

you will use this non Scrollable listview in the child.xml layout by adding it as a customized UI component

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >


    <com.youpackage.uiutils.NonScrollableListView
        android:id="@+id/non_scrollable_listview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Where i need to call this onMeasure function and  in  which adapter... can you explain

Comment: You will use this customized listview as the child item of the listview  , but from the memory prescriptive its not a good work around. Try to use Expandable listview instead. I found this tutorial which helped me alot developing my first expandble list: http://androidtrainningcenter.blogspot.in/2012/07/android-expandable-listview-simple.html

Answer (score 0):

You can [ExpandableListView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html) in place of making custom view also for data handling you can use [ExpandableListAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListAdapter.html).

Comment: Not able to work on ExpandableListview now, can any one help me on above code only

Comment: @Android  The way which you are trying is totally impossible thing to manage. You can not add listview inside listview. The `ExpandableListView` is the only solution for this kind of requirements.